# How to designate a human production which enables/stimulates/fosters reflection on a given topic?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering how to designate a human production (e.g. a book, a film, a painting) which manages to enable, to stimulate, to foster reflection on a particular matter or debate. Note that the intent of the work is not to provide a clear-cut answer to the foresaid matter, but rather to make you think about it, maybe by being ambiguous and displaying (explicitly or implicitly) various sides of the debate.

Some terms I have thought of are:

- A **support**, e.g. *her new novel about Eskimos and Berbers can serve as a **support** to think about the potential consequences of climate change on our daily lives*;
- A **vector**, e.g. *the film served as a **vector** to reflect on the inequalities between men and women on the workplace*;
- A **catalyst**, e.g. *Mondrian's paintings **catalysed** my reflections on what art is*.

But they do not sound very "elegant" (i.e. literary) to me. Is there a more precise word for what I want to say?

Comment: What do you mean by the three words not sounding elegant? Why are they not elegant?

Comment: @JasonBassford I am looking for something with a literary touch to it, which I think those 3 examples I gave do not really have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it ***intriguing***:

> arousing one's curiosity or interest; fascinating.
>
> - e.g. an intriguing story ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02pbFeC5RwejO0tCyg38gk0jh6dqA%3A1612036332966&ei=7LgVYLHHOoai1fAPjO2VqAI&q=intriguing&oq=intriguing&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIKCAAQsQMQQxCLAzIKCAAQFBCHAhCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIFCAAQiwMyBQgAEIsDMgUIABCLAzIFCAAQiwMyBQgAEIsDOgUIABCRAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOggILhCxAxCDAToFCAAQsQM6AggAOgIILjoECCMQJzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6CggAEJECEEYQ-QE6CggAELEDEBQQhwI6DQgAELEDEBQQhwIQiwM6BwgAEBQQhwI6BwgAEAoQiwNQuYIlWJSPJWDqliVoAHACeACAAZwEiAHFEJIBCTAuNy4zLjUtMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXq4AQPAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwix7fant8TuAhUGURUIHYx2BSUQ4dUDCA0&uact=5))

There is also the compound adjective ***thought-provoking***:

> making you think a lot about a subject:
>
> - e.g. a thought-provoking book/film ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thought-provoking))

As verbs you could use ***inspire, trigger, prompt***.

Comment: +1 for "prompt", I seldom use this verb but it's true it actually fits what I am thinking about, and it has a nice touch to it. Thanks.

Comment: Marking as answered as I don't expect new answers and "prompt" is actually very close to what I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen 'Treatise' [used figuratively](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&content=novel+is+an+essay%2Cnovel+is+a+treatise%2C+painting+is+a+treatise%2C+painting+is+an+essay%2Cfilm+is+an+essay&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnovel%20is%20an%20essay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnovel%20is%20a%20treatise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpainting%20is%20an%20essay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfilm%20is%20an%20essay%3B%2Cc0) for this.  e.g. "Her novel is a treatise on the potential consequences of climate change on our daily lives."

Which doesn't quite fit the formal definition, as most novels, movies or paintings are not Systematic, but I think would be well understood [MW:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treatise)

> a systematic exposition or argument in writing including a methodical
> discussion of the facts and principles involved and conclusions
> reached

Treatise doesn't seem to be used very often at all for artwork, but Essay is a synonym that does seem to be used to describe paintings quite commonly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the appropriate choice from *stimulate*, *stimulus* and *stimulation* would suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

Trailblazer

"one that blazes a trail to guide others"

Merriam-Webster Dictionary

Alternative answer: Spur